# I need to communicate between 2 pages without refreshing the page, with ajax,  when a event is raised on the serverside

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, events

To clearify, I've tried solutions with `updatepanel`/`scriptmanager` but I do NOT want to use them.
I want to make this jquery-ajax posts and nothing else.

Lets assume this scenario.

We have a global event as follows:

```
public static class CustomGlobalEvents

{

    public delegate void SpecialEventRaisedEventHandler(object sender, string type, string msg);

    public static event SpecialEventRaisedEventHandler SpecialEventRaised;

    public static void SpecialEvent(object sender, string type, string msg)
    {
        if (SpecialEventRaised != null)
            SpecialEventRaised(sender, type, msg);
    }

}
```

We have 2 web-pages, reciever.aspx and sender.aspx.

reciever.aspx has the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        CustomGlobalEvents.SpecialEventRaised += new CustomGlobalEvents.SpecialEventRaisedEventHandler(CustomGlobalEvents_SpecialEventRaised);
    }

}

void CustomGlobalEvents_SpecialEventRaised(object sender, string type, string msg)
{
    // do something
}
```

sender.aspx has the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(!IsPostBack)

    {
         CustomGlobalEvents.SpecialEvent(this.Page, "type", "msg");
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do in the `reciever.aspx` event handler for the special event `CustomGlobalEvents_SpecialEventRaised` is that I want to fire a javascript on the reciever.aspx page.

Like doing a jquery ajax post and updating the information on the page.

I have tried with injecting a javascript to a scriptmanager but since the scriptmanager is not in a async state (even if I force a update with `updatePanel.Update();`) the script does not get to the page.

Another idea was to try to initiate a generichandler directly, but this resulted in `sender.aspx` getting the response instead of the reciever with the following code:

```
MyGenericHandler myGenericHandler = new MyGenericHandler();
myGenericHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

which might make sense since its the sender.aspx that actually fired the event in the first place.

With this, nothing happens at all:

```
MyGenericHandler myGenericHandler = new MyGenericHandler();
myGenericHandler.ProcessRequest(this.Context);
```

The best method would obiously be to fire the `generichandler` and in some way make the `reciever.aspx` page recieve the response. The next best thing would be to tell reciever.aspx to fire a javascript method.

I've tried to create a `httpmodule` to try to hook something up, but failed.

Best other solution I've seen so far is to actually by jquery do a ajax post every x seconds. But this is defenatly NOT what I want. I want to fire it when it needs to be fired (when the server-side event fires).

Solutions working with IIS6 or IIS7, any is fine, but its ASP.NET 3.5 and not MVC.

Any ideas?

Edit: apparently doesn't stackoverflow's -tag public delegates... :)

Comment: You just want a client side event from sender.aspx to send an update to receiver.aspx?

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be clientside from sender.aspx, but sure, that would work aswell.

And the 2 pages are not on the same browser.. Think of it like a chat or something.

Comment: Bottomline, I'd like to get javascript to subscribe to server-events...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think thats possible. For a response to exist there must be a request. Server cannot push something to the client. Your client code has to check for server status.